# PostgreSQL: Insert if not exist and then Select

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert

## Question

Imagine having the following PostgreSQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE setting (
  user_id bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  language lang NOT NULL DEFAULT 'english',
  foo bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  bar bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true
);
```

From my research, I know to `INSERT` a row with the default values if the row for the specific user did not exist, would look something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO setting  (user_id)
    SELECT %s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM setting WHERE user_id = %s)
```

(where the `%s` are placeholders where I would provide the User's ID)

I also know to get the user's setting (aka to `SELECT`) I can do the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM setting WHERE user_id = %s
```

However, I am trying to combine the two, where I can retrieve the user's setting, and **if** the setting for the particular user does not exist yet, `INSERT` default values and return those values.

## Example

So it would look something like this:

Imagine `Alice` has her *setting* already saved in the database but `Bob` is a new user and does not have it.

When we execute the magical SQL query with `Alice`'s user ID, it will return `Alice`'s setting stored in the database. If we execute the same identical magical SQL query on `Bob`'s user ID, it will detect that `Bob` does not have any *setting* saved in the database , thus it will `INSERT` a *setting* record with all default values, and then return `Bob`'s newly created setting.

Comment: You have to use a UNIQUE constraint, the current check using a SELECT statement is useless. You can't see uncommitted rows. Let the INSERT fail or use an ON CONFLICT declaration. RETURNING can return the user_id that has been created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there is an UNIQUE or PK constraint on `user_id` as Frank Heikens said then try to insert, if it violates the constraint do nothing and return the inserted row (if any) in the `t` CTE, union it with a 'proper' select and pick the first row only. The optimizer will take care than no extra select is done if the insert returns a row.

```sql
with t as
(
 insert into setting (user_id) values (%s)
 on conflict do nothing
 returning *
)
select * from t
union all
select * from setting where user_id = %s
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

No magic necessary.  Use `returning` and `union all`:

```
with inparms as ( -- Put your input parameters in CTE so you bind only once
  select %s::bigint as user_id
), cond_insert as ( -- Insert the record if not exists, returning *
  insert into settings (user_id)
  select i.user_id
    from inparms i
   where not exists (select 1 from settings where user_id = i.user_id)
  returning *
)
select *              -- If a record was inserted, get it
  from cond_insert
union all
select s.*            -- If not, then get the pre-existing record
  from inparms i
       join settings s on s.user_id = i.user_id;
```

Comment: This is a more advanced SQL query than I usually deal with. Can I ask for a short explanation of what is going on in the SQL query in your answer?

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner  I added comments to the query in my answer.  Please let me know if you need more explanation.